# object of type NoneType has no len()

Tags: python

I don't know where is the problem with this code. I get a clear array of music words, but when I select random word it gives me 'NoneType' error.

```
def take_words_from_file():
music_words = []
file_name = 'secret.txt'
open_file = open(file_name,'r',encoding='utf-8')
i = open_file
for words in i.read().split():
    music_words.append(words)
print(music_words)

def take_a_word_random(word):
    word = random.choice(take_words_from_file())
    return word.lower() # make sure every word is lower case
```

Error :

```
Object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: `take_words_from_file()` doesn't return anything, so you're passing None to `random.choice`.

Comment: In `take_words_from_file`, you are using `print` to print the `music_words` list, but you're not `return`ing anything. You should `return music_words`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy mistake:

```
def take_words_from_file():
    music_words = []
    file_name = 'secret.txt'
    open_file = open(file_name,'r',encoding='utf-8')
    i = open_file
    for words in i.read().split():
        music_words.append(words)
    print(music_words)
    #here
    return music_words
```

When you write a function and dont specify a return, python automatically returns `None` and `random.choice` is performing a sanity check on the type of object provided.

Ultimately, if `music_words` is not iterable, it cant give you a random choice because there's nothing to choose from.

Comment: thanks for sharing your answer